# Solving a trig equation that is quadratic?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have to solve for $x$  given

$$\tan^2 x  = 2 + \tan x\;\;\;\;\;\;0≤x≤2\pi$$

I brought it all to one side and set it all equal to zero like:

$$\tan^2 x - \tan x - 2 = 0$$

What am i supposed to do from there to solve for x?

Comment: Hint:  if you let $z=\tan x$ you get a quadratic equation in $z$.

Comment: so essentially z^2 - z - 2 = 0? I was told to use the quadratic formula but not sure how it works in the case of tanx. Or I could keep it in this "z" form and factor out a z?

Comment: So...can you solve that quadratic for $z$?  You should get two values $r_1,r_2$ and then you just have $x=\tan^{-1} r_i$.

Comment: That's the part I'm stuck on, how can I solve that?

Comment: $\tan^2 x-\tan x-2=(\tan x+1)(\tan x-2)=0$ if and only if either $\tan x=-1$ or $\tan x=2$, i.e. if and only if either $x=\arctan(-1)+\pi k=-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k$ or $x=\arctan 2+\pi m$ for some $k,m\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You can solve $z^2-z-2=0$ by the quadratic equation (if you must).  But it has a simple factoring as well (already pointed out in some of the comments and posts).

Comment: Hint: In the expression $z^2-z-2$, $z$ is a number. Hint 2: In the expression $\tan^2 x -\tan x - 2$, $\tan x$ is a number.

Answer (score 1):

For $\tan x=z$ you have:
$$
z^2-z-2=0 \rightarrow z_1=-1 \quad z_2=2
$$

so you have :
$$
\tan x = -1 \quad \lor \quad \tan x = 2
$$

can you solve these?

Comment: Yes this is I part I dont understand, where on earth did the -1 and 2 come from. My teacher wrote -2 and 1 instead.

Comment: Also a teacher can do a mistake! can you solve the equation and verify?

Comment: yes so for tan inverse of -1 its just ipi/4, and tan inverse of 2 is 1.107. Are those the two correct answers?

Comment: Yes. For $\tan x = -1$ you have $x=-\pi/4 +k \pi$ and for  $\tan x=2$ you have $x=\arctan (2)+k \pi= 1.107148717794090503017065... + k \pi$

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic factors as $z^2-z-2=(z+1)(z-2)$. So by setting $z=\tan{x}$ we get

$$\tan{x}=-1\text{ or }\tan{x}=2$$

This leads to $x=-\pi/4+k\pi$ or $x=\tan^{-1}{2}+k\pi$

Comment: ohh i understand, and to solve for x you took the tan inverse of both. Not sure what +kpi means however.

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui More generally, $\tan x=a$ if and only if $x=\arctan a+\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, i.e. all the solutions $x$ are $\arctan a$, $\arctan a+\pi$, $\arctan +2\pi$, $\arctan a -\pi$, $\arctan a-2\pi$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You began with:

$ \tan^2 x = 2 + \tan x $.

---

As you mentioned, bring all terms to the L.H.S.:

$ \tan^2 x - \tan x - 2 = 0 $

---

Now let:

$ y = \tan z $.

---

As a result:

$ y^2 - y - 2 = 0 $

---

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $y$.

$ y = \frac{-(-1) \pm \sqrt{(-1)^2 - 4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)} $
$ = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{9}}{2} $
$ = \frac{1 \pm 3}{2} $
$ = \frac{1 + 3}{2}, \frac{1 - 3}{2} $
$ = \frac{4}{2}, \frac{-2}{2} $
$ = 2, -1 $

---

Since $y = 2, -1 $, and $ y = \tan z $:

$ \tan z = 2, -1 $

---

From there:

$ z = \arctan 2, \arctan-1 $

Comment: Thank you, this format is easy to read! I have never been tough the word arctan but I assume it means to take the tan inverse of both numbers!

Comment: Yes, $\arctan x$ is the inverse function of $\tan x$. I don't use $\tan^{-1} x$ because it can easily be mistaken for "1 over $\tan x$".

Comment: Oh ok that's fine, I'm in Canada so it may be differently said here. Thank you so much for the help, I always come here for the math homework questions I don't understand, everyone on this forum is amazing.

Comment: Yes, I'm a student too, and I'm usually the one asking for help. :)

Comment: Also, to mark your question as solved, please put a check on the solution.